# How to Assign Random String to 2D Array

Tags: c, arrays, string, random

The program reads a file which includes one word in every line.After reading random word put random word in a pointer and return the pointer .in main function
printf("%s",func("example.txt",str)) it prints different string when the program run.I want to do this in 2d array(20*20) like table,but i could not imagine how to do this.When i print the  the function in internal loop,it give me the same word in every loop step.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char *word(char *file, char *str);

int main() {
    char *str ;
    int i, j;

    str = (char *)malloc(20);
    srand(time(NULL));
    char *puzzle[20][20];

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            puzzle[i][j] = word("words.txt", str);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            printf("%s     ", puzzle[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

char *word(char *file, char *str) {
    int end, loop, line;


    FILE *fd = fopen(file, "r");

    if (fd == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
        return (NULL);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    line = rand() % 100 + 1;

    for (end = loop = 0; loop < line; ++loop) {
        if (0 == fgets(str, 20, fd)) {
            end = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!end)
        return (char *)str;

    fclose(fd);
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: Standard `main` snippet decoration is a close answer to your question. Try creating a pointer array (like; `char *a[sizeRow][sizeCol]`), then define corresponding string for each pointer (for example; `a[2][3] = strdup(...)`).

Comment: Thank you it is useful but still i could not imagine where should i  call to other function whic return pointer and i need this,cause the other function return just one random adress every time it runs.And assigning one by one would not random i think

Comment: You'd better show your initial effort & code, so I (or somebody else) can help to figure it out if any error exists.

Comment: İt is edited.,and i know puzzle[i][j]=word("words.txt",str);
 is not logical

Comment: Let me digest first. (1) Is your array 20 x 20 = 400 words of variable length or 20 words each having 20 characters at most (it seems the latter, is it correct)? (2) Do you want read 20 words (or 400 words, depending on your answer in part 1) at once?

Comment: edit:max 20 character at every row or column cause it is 20*20 table.And I will take 10 words from the file. Every string's(word) length might be different
Where I want to print (string start) will be random and if there is a space after 10 words, I will print random letters there, but now this is not my primary problem.@ssd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have your `words.txt` file, so I've created some random strings below.

And a note:

- Because your nested loop is in the `main`, your code opens the file in the sub function and returns w/o closing it; then returns to the sub and reopens, and again, and again... It's always better to read at once and close the file before returning from the sub.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char **word(int countString, int maxChars) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    // allocate memory for pointers that are pointing to each string
    char **arrStr = malloc(countString * sizeof(char *));

    // srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < countString; i++) {
        // create a random string with a length of 'k'
        // say, 5 <= k <= maxChars
        // that (+ 1) is for the string terminating character '\0'
        k = (rand() % (maxChars - 5)) + 5 + 1;
        // allocate memory for string
        arrStr[i] = malloc(k * sizeof(char));

        for (j = 0; j < k - 1; j++) {
            *(arrStr[i] + j) = rand() % 26 + 'A';
        }

        *(arrStr[i] + j) = '\0';
    }

    return arrStr;
}

int main() {
    int countString = 10;
    int maxChars = 20;
    char **arrStr = NULL;
    int i;

    arrStr = word(countString, maxChars);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", *(arrStr + i));
    }

    // do not forget to free the strings
    // and then the string pointers (array)

    return 0;
}
```